# ideal settings for mp3 + jpeg to video output?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take mp3's and jpg's and output them to a video file, with the intention they'll be uploaded to youtube. I'm wondering what the ideal settings would be. One stipulation, however, is that I want the mp3 stream to be used without it being reencoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* work:

```
ffmpeg -i soundfile.mp3 -i imagefile.jpg -c:a copy -c:v mjpeg output.mp4
```

Explanation:

`-c:a copy`: Use the "copy" codec for the audio data.

`-c:v mjpeg`: Use the Motion-JPEG codec for the static artwork.  This is what's used in most MP3 files with embedded album art.

The resulting file, however, may or may not work for you.  `ffplay` plays it just fine, displaying the image.  `mplayer` prints a warning about your machine being too slow, but the audio plays fine.  `mplayer2`, however, doesn't display the image at all, and prints a sea of warnings, but plays the audio just fine.  I don't know the reason for the different behaviors.

I wouldn't get too invested about the MP3 being a perfect copy, though -- YouTube is going to re-encode the thing, anyway.